# Getting errors while running matlab from java

Tags: java, matlab

MatlabEngine eng = Matlabengine.startMatlab(); this line gives the following errors

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 'void com.mathworks.mvm.MvmFactory.nativeSetJavaEngine(boolean)'
at com.mathworks.mvm.MvmFactory.nativeSetJavaEngine(Native Method)
at com.mathworks.mvm.MvmImpl.setJavaEngineMode(MvmImpl.java:203)
at com.mathworks.engine.MatlabEngine.<clinit>(MatlabEngine.java:69)
at org.fog.test.perfeval.MyProject.main(MyProject.java:63)
```

Comment: Did you add Matlab library to your path?

Comment: Yes, I have added but getting same error.

Comment: I am using matlab2015a.